# Java NetBeans and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing

How to check if the value that I put in the jtextfield and combobox are already in my database? I can't find any errors and I have tried other ways, but it just doesn't work and doesn't open the other windows.

```
private void hyrButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    conn = LidhjaMeDB.LidhDB();

    // PER FAQEN HYRESE
    String Sql = "Select perdorues_emer=?, password=?,  kategori=? from punonjes_password ";

    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
        String str1 = userJtxt.getText().toString();
        String str2 = userJtxt.getText().toString();
        String cb1 = (String) kategoriJcb.getSelectedItem();
        pst.setString(1, str1);
        pst.setString(2, str2);
        pst.setString(3, cb1);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        String txt1 = rs.getString("perdorues_emer");
        String txt2 = rs.getString("password");
        String cb2 = rs.getString("kategori");

        while (rs.next()) {

            if (txt1 == str1 && txt2 == str2) {

                if (kategoriJcb.getSelectedItem() == "Financa") {
                    Financa f = new Financa();
                    f.setVisible(true);
                } else if (kategoriJcb.getSelectedItem() == "Prenotimet") {
                    Rezervime r = new Rezervime();
                    r.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    Fatura fa = new Fatura();
                    fa.setVisible(true);
                }

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Te dhenat nuk egzistojne ne databaze", "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
}
```

Comment: Downvote for stupid title; the result of `getText()` is already a `String`; and Netbeans has nothing to do with it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query looks weird, probably you meant your query to be like

```
   String Sql = "Select perdorues_emer, `password`,  kategori from punonjes_password ";
```

You can't write your query like `Select perdorues_emer=?` that's a wrong syntax altogether.

Comment: says parameter index out of range

Comment: per your query there is no need of passing any parameter.

Comment: thank you, i have tried other ways too but dont know why it doesnt work